# On click of a div should route to another url in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to redirect to other url when I click on a div using angularjs.can anyone please help me out ...

My html:

```
 <div ng-click="redirectTo()">
    <p>Hello</p>
    </div>

My js:



  angular.module('myApp')
   .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
                            function ($scope,$rootScope) {

      $scope.redirectTo = function(){

        ===============

        }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using states then use :

```
<div data-ui-sref="// your state" >
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Or if you want to use `on-click` event then use :

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$state',
                        function ($scope,$state) {
 $scope.redirectTo = function(){
     $state.go('// you state',null);
 }
    }
}]);
```

HTML TEMPLATE

```
<div ng-click="redirectTo()">
   <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: You should go through this [ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)

Answer (score 1):

```
  angular.module('myApp')
   .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope','$location',
                            function ($scope,$rootScope,$location) {

      $scope.redirectTo = function(){

         $location.url('/home');

        }
}]);
```

Comment: Here where should I use $location in the controller

Comment: Inside controller you can use. you need to inject $location in controller.   .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope','$location',
                            function ($scope,$rootScope, $location)

Comment: it Working? if yes means can you tick my answer.

Comment: yes its working.If it is home,then how should I redirect to templateURL using route provider

Comment: {
    "Home": {
        "url": "/Home",
        "templateUrl": "Home.html"
    },

    "Page1": {
        "url": "/page1",
        "templateUrl": "Page1.html"
    },

    "Page2": {
        "url": "/page2",
        "templateUrl": "page2.html"
    },
    "Page3": {
        "url": "/page3",
        "templateUrl": "Page3.html"
    }
}   Sample provider whatever url your set it will call corresponding  templateurl based on that page will load